# Search through all columns of data

Tags: postgresql

I have a table, for example Products, and it has 10 columns. There are also other tables, which are related to Products.

For example:

```
Products <-> Keywords (M-M)
Products <-> Warehouse (1-M)
```

etc

I need to implement a search on all columns, as well as on the columns in the relationship Keywords and Warehouse.

I have a trivial SQL

```
FROM Product AS A
LEFT JOIN (...Keywords...) AS B
LEFT JOIN (...Warehouse...) AS C
WHERE "A.Name" LIKE '%SOME TEXT%' OR "A.RegistrationDate" LIKE '%SOME TEXT%' etc.
```

I.e. the user enters a string and needs to search through all columns of the table (they contain int, datetme, text types) using this string.

I think my implementation is very naive and not really optimized.

Is there any other way to search string in all columns?
Also I had an idea to put all this in to_vector and search through full text search, Is that a good idea? I just have DateTime and Int types in my columns

Comment: truth to be told, if you want to match to every single column.. its a bad idea for using database. you would be better off with some independent indexing application to handle that kind of stuff (e.g. elasticsearch). that being said, you can convert date to string using [`TO_CHAR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes, I guess I could use ES, but what's the algorithm? In order to achieve the result. What do I need to do?

Comment: Note that `"A.Name"` should be `a."Name"` - but you should [really avoid](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) those dreaded quoted identifiers

Answer (score 1):

A brute force method would be to convert the entire *row* to a string and then search that string:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Product AS a
  LEFT JOIN (...Keywords...) AS B
  LEFT JOIN (...Warehouse...) AS C
WHERE a::text LIKE '%SOME TEXT%'
```

Note that casting a row to a text value will separate the column values with commas and enclose it with parentheses, e.g. a row with the values `1, Donald, Duck` would become `'(1,Donald,Duck)'`

So if you are looking for commas or parentheses you might get false positives.

Another options that is more accurate but a bit more complicated, is to turn the row into JSON, then iterate over all JSON values:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Product AS a
  LEFT JOIN (...Keywords...) AS B
  LEFT JOIN (...Warehouse...) AS C
WHERE EXISTS (select *
              from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(a)) as x(col,value)
              where x.value LIKE '%SOME TEXT%')
```

Or you can use a JSON path query instead:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Product AS a
  LEFT JOIN (...Keywords...) AS B
  LEFT JOIN (...Warehouse...) AS C
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(to_jsonb(a), '$.* ? (@ like_regex "SOME TEXT")')
```