# Searching for a value from all of my SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and I would like to get row/rows(depending on the query), by giving it a value and searching all of the available columns of my table.

How would I go about checking every column for a value ? I also am looking at checking for different types of values

Comment: Hi, this sentence of yours sounds very complicated to me. Do you have example data of  what you want to do ? Or do you just want an ordinary select with where clause ?

Comment: say i have a value of 'test' and i would like to get all the rows with the value of 'test' in them regardless of the column. there might be 'test' in column A and another in column B

Comment: Try this:  `select * from mytable where mytable::text like '%test%';`

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that im also looking at using different data type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677974/search-through-all-columns-of-data

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are a and b and the text you are searching for is 'test' then something like this will do the trick:

```
select *
from table1
where 'test' in (a, b);
```

Note: this will only work if all your columns have the same datatype and the same datatype with the value you search for.

Comment: but what if i have 20 columns. or 50. would i have to type all the columns. isnt there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I do not know of any.